# How to prove $L \cdot L^{*} = L^{+}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

How can one formally prove

$L \cdot L^{*} = L^{+}$

It looks obvious to me since with the concatenation you get rid of $\varepsilon$, but I cannot think of a formal proof through induction or something.

Comment: ? this is by definition

Comment: Or if not by definition, a small step away from the definitions.

Comment: What about a concrete example :$L=\{0,1\}$? Can you extend this to a finite alphabet?

Comment: Well, I would say $L \cdot L^{*} = L \cdot \bigcup_{i \ge 0} L^{i} = \bigcup_{i \ge 1}L^{i} = L^{+}$ However, this is an old exercise I found and the task is to use induction, which seems not necessary to me.

Comment: @user1658887 Your proof looks good enough for me. Perhaps they wanted you to use induction on $i$, though this seems pointless since you won't be using the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I don't see how induction can be used here. You can't get from $\bigcup_{i=0}^n$ to $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty$ by induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the comments.

A. Sometimes $L^+$ is **defined** to be $L\circ L^*$, where '$\circ$' is the  concatenations operator.

B. Assume the following definitions,

> $L^* \equiv \{\varepsilon\} \cup L \cup L^2 \cup \cdots$
>
> $L^+\equiv L \cup L^2 \cup \cdots$

Then, by the properties of the concatenation operator, $L\circ L^i = L^{i+1}$. Explicitly for the case of $i=0$, it also holds that $L\circ\{\epsilon\} = L$.

Then,
$$\begin{align}
L\circ L^* &= L \circ \left(  \{\varepsilon\} \cup L \cup L^2 \cup \cdots \right )
\\ &= (L\circ \{\varepsilon\}) \cup (L\circ L) \cup (L \circ L^2) \cup \cdots \\ &= L \cup L^2 \cup \cdots \\ &\equiv L^+
\end{align}$$

The only missing part is to explain the second transition--The distributivity of the concatenation operator over unions.

Comment: Thx. Just to make sure: You would also say that induction does not make any sense in this case?

Comment: As Raphael wrote above, induction is problematic when talking about $n=\infty$, although it can be used to prove for any arbitrary large (but finite) $n$.